# Rust lifetime issue with manually dropped reference wrapper

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a class in Rust with custom drop logic that wraps a mutable reference, but no matter what I do, I can't get the lifetimes to work out, and the compiler error messages haven't helped. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Note: I already tried every modification to this code that I could think of, such as removing or reversing the `'b: 'a` constraint, but no matter what I do, the compiler produces one kind of inscrutable lifetime error message or another.

```rust
pub struct MapRef<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V>{
    p: &'a mut HashMap<K, V>,
}
impl<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V> MapRef<'a, K, V> {
    pub fn new(p: &'a mut HashMap<K, V>) -> Self {Self{p}}
}
impl<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V> MapRef<'a, K, V> {
    pub fn reborrow<'b: 'a>(&'b mut self) -> MapRef<'b, K, V> {
        Self::new(self.p)
    }
}
impl<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V> Drop for MapRef<'a, K, V> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropping ref");
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test() -> Result<(), String> {
        let mut m: HashMap<(), ()> = HashMap::new();
        let mut r1 = MapRef::new(&mut m);

        {
            let r2 = r1.reborrow();
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Example error message:

```
   |
37 |             let r2 = r1.reborrow();
   |                      ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
41 |     }
   |     -
   |     |
   |     `r1` dropped here while still borrowed
   |     borrow might be used here, when `r1` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `util::MapRef`
```

Comment: Your lifetime parameters for `reborrow` do not make sense.

Comment: The new lifetime `'b` is pointless because you are restricting it to outlive the struct itself. It may as well just be `'a`. Since this is a mutable reference, you can't do anything with it without borrowing it for _exactly_ the same lifetime as the struct itself.

Comment: @PeterHall I already tried it without the extra lifetime parameter, and that didn't work either. I added the `'b` in an unsuccessful attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, but just adding lifetime arguments is not going to help - it just makes things more complicated.

Comment: Well, like I said, I tried every permutation of the code I could think of. I had to pick one to post to SO. Anyway, the question remains - how would you modify the code so the test compiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the reason the compiler suggests adding the erroneous `'b: 'a` constraint is because the `Self` in `Self::new` is implicitly referring to the `'a` lifetime. The solution is to change `Self::new` to `MapRef::new`, which allows you to drop the bad constraint.

```rust
impl<'a, K: Eq + Hash, V> MapRef<'a, K, V> {
    pub fn reborrow<'b>(&'b mut self) -> MapRef<'b, K, V> {
        MapRef::new(self.p)
    }
}
```

Note that `'b` can now be elided, but I left it in here for clarity.